# Как правильно реализовать удаление и редактирование сообщений aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть бот-модератор. И в нём есть команда /del, которая удаляет сообщение на которое ответили с этой командой:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["del"])
async def deleteMsg(message: types.Message):
    if isAdmin(message):
        await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
        await message.delete()
    else: 
        await message.answer("У вас нет прав для данного дейтсвия")
```

Но иногда, по какой-то причине выскакивает ошибка `message can't be deleted`, я узнал что телеграмм может запрещать удаление сообщений в закрытых чатах, и узнал, что надо просто изменять текст сообщения на *"удалено"*
Как это реализовать? В aiogram я нашел метод для редактирования сообщений только от бота:

```
await bot.edit_message_text(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id, text="<i>Удалено<i>", parse_mode="HTML")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await bot.edit_message_text("<i>Удалено<i>", message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id, parse_mode="HTML")
```

У `bot.edit_message_text` параметры идут так: *текст сообщения*, *id чата*, *id сообщения*, и остальные параметры (типа `parse_mode` и `reply_markup`).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]